# How would I make a wireless pressure switch for turning on and off a flash light?

Tags: rf, wireless, transmitter, receiver

I want to make a wireless pressure switch for a flash light mounted on an airsoft gun

I have figured out that I would have to use an RF transmitter/receiver like this one:

[https://www.amazon.com/3-7-12V-Wireless-Control-Transmitter-Controller/dp/B08F7FFQ14](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08F7FFQ14)

However, I have found some information that says the frequency at which this device operates (433 Mhz) as well as others may be illegal in the U.S. Is this information correct and is there any other way I could make this kind of device?

The transmitter/receiver would only be roughly 2 ft apart, so I'm not worried about range.

If you know of a system or device that already has this kind of purpose please link some information about it.

Comment: Could you describe your idea of a wireless pressure switch in more detail? Where is the switch, what does it switch, how are things powered? What part must be wireless and (what I'm most curious about) why?

Comment: In any case, for a simple on/off signal and at such a short distance an alternative to RF may be some kind of optical signal or, if you can move this even closer, something using induction. Or ultrasound propagated through the gun body? Lots of possibilities.

Comment: Am I dreaming or do you want to replace a 30cm easy wire connection by a RF thing with two independent parts, dealing with batteries just for the pleasure ?
If so, you will find many wireless switch module on aliexpress way cheaper than the labour you're trying to put on this project.